# How many directional lights in Unity

Tags: unity

In Unity, how many directional lights can be active at once? 1, 2, 4, or 8? I thought 2, but I have searched and cannot confirm.

Comment: lmao how are you posting from a test?

Comment: What kind of weird modern engine would impose a limit like that? Back in 2002 I was doing 6 per-pixel lights _per-pass_ on Radeon 9700 hardware. With modern instruction limits and multi-pass rendering this all seems absurd to me.

Answer (score 1):

here there's a general answer to the question

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/434512/limit-to-number-of-lights.html

"Pixel Light Count, which is settable in Edit->ProjectSettings->Quality.

..there is a "priority" variable on the lights which determines which show and which hide. The highest priority also become Pixel-shaded lights. And I'm assuming the closest get higher priority if they match."

plus

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27212/lighting-in-unity-indie-limited.html

" Use vertex lights (max 8 per object, unlimited per scene) or increase the number of pixel lights in the quality settings (max 8 total)."

plus

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/437215/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-lights.html

"The maximum number of lights used on a single renderer depends on the shader being used and also on the quality settings for the number of point lights: Edit > Project Settings > Quality. Normally you don't allow more than 4 to affect an object:"

Comment: Please edit to include the relevant information in your post.  Link-only answers are subject to link rot, and not directly helpful to future visitors (they have to filter through noisy external sites to get their answer).